# Extending a model class in Yii 1.x

Tags: php, yii, model, parent-child, extends

I am having trouble extending an AR model class. I have a table `jobs` and three other tables which have a 1 to 1 relation with jobs. `detailsgeoscan`, `detailsseismic`, `details3d`. I have a model for all 4 tables extending `CActiveRecord`. I would like to change this so `detailsgeoscan` extends `jobs`. I have replace the class line as follows

```
class Detailsgeoscan extends Jobs
```

Problem i have is how do i access and set parent model fields?

for example currently i am querying `jobs` then `detailsgeoscan`, i want to query `detailsgeoscan` model and be able to see all fields of `jobs` table and `detailsgeoscan` and be able to update/create/delete rows accordingly.

**UPDATE**

how would i rewrite the following. `PROJID` is in parent class.

```
Detailsgeoscan::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"PROJID=".$model->PROJID));
```

Comment: `parent::someFunction()` and `parent::someVar`. But why you do not use relations of Yii?

Comment: So if `PROJID` is attribute of parent of `$model`, than `$model` can access it's parents elements like it's self: `$model->PROJID`, just like every `$model` will have `attributes` atribute of parent class in CActiveRecord

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: don't.

Long answer: you can do what you are after (multi-table inheritance), but it is a real pain. Do you have unit testing set up? Are you comfortable using it? You'll need it in order to make things work well. There are a lot of gotchas to main things work smoothly.

I've done it once and wouldn't do it again. The benefits long term didn't seem worth the headaches and complexity that came with it.

Comment: problem i have: 2 cjui tabs, 1 display `jobs` and other displaying `detailsgeoscan`. if i go to 1 tab, say JOBS, and sort it, i want the GEOSCAN tab to reflect same sort data.